# Wrong number of arguments error in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec

I'm trying to build an api with ruby on rails by following this book: http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/

However I encountered a problem in Chapter 5, while writing tests for authentication.

I'm using Rails Rails 4.0.2 and rspec 3.1.7.

The test code will like below:

```
describe "#authenticate_with_token" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      authentication.stub(:current_user).and_return(nil)
      response.stub(:response_code).and_return(401)
      response.stub(:body).and_return({"errors" => "Not authenticated"}.to_json)
      authentication.stub(:response).and_return(response)
    end

    it "render a json error message" do
      expect(json_response[:errors]).to eql "Not authenticated"
    end

    it {  should respond_with 401 }
  end
```

(Please see Listing 5.11 on http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_five)

And when I run the test I get the following error:

```
 1) Authenticable#authenticate_with_token render a json error message
     Failure/Error: response.stub(:response_code).and_return(401)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/controllers/concerns/authenticable_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authenticable#authenticate_with_token 
     Failure/Error: response.stub(:response_code).and_return(401)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/controllers/concerns/authenticable_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I also tried to write my code without using stub like the following:

```
allow(authentication).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
allow(response).to receive(:response_code).and_return(401)
allow(response).to receive(:body).and_return({"errors" => "Not authenticated"}.to_json)
allow(authentication).to receive(:response).and_return(response)
```

But I'm still getting the wrong number arguments error:

```
Failures:

  1) Authenticable#authenticate_with_token render a json error message
     Failure/Error: allow(response).to receive(:response_code).and_return(401)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/controllers/concerns/authenticable_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authenticable#authenticate_with_token 
     Failure/Error: allow(response).to receive(:response_code).and_return(401)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/controllers/concerns/authenticable_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

That would be great if you can help me,

Thanks!

Comment: What versions of Rails and RSpec are you using?

Comment: It is probably a version problem with rspec, make sure you lock the version of rspec to 2.14 like so: `gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14"` you will probably have to delete the `Gemfile.lock` file and then run the bundle install command

Comment: Hi @dnunez24 I'm using Rails Rails 4.0.2 and rspec 3.1.7.

Comment: It would help if you'd identify the line at which the failure is occurring (i.e. line 33 of `authenticable_spec.rb`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

`allow(response).to receive(:status).and_return(401)
it { expect(response.status).to eq(401) }`